# Why does "a".::(List()) report error ":: is not member of string"?

Tags: scala

See this:

```
scala> 1 + 1
res0: Int = 2

scala> 1.+(1)
warning: there were 1 deprecation warning(s); re-run with -deprecation for details
res1: Double = 2.0

scala> "a" :: List()
res2: List[String] = List(a)

scala> "a".::(List())
<console>:8: error: value :: is not a member of String
              "a".::(List())
                  ^
```

Why does the error occur?

Comment: Your example with addition doesn't do what you seem to think it does. It's parsed as `1. + 2` (`1.` being the same as `1.0`), which is why you get a double as the result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
List().::("a")
```

The reason is that :: is a method of List.

From **ScalaByExample**:

> Like any infix operator, :: is also implemented as a method of an
>   object. In this case, the object is the list that is extended. This is
>   possible, because operators ending with a ‘:’ character are treated
>   specially in Scala. All such operators are treated as methods of their
>   right operand. E.g.,

```
x :: y = y.::(x) whereas x + y = x.+(y)
```

> Note, however, that operands of a binary operation are in each case
>   evaluated from left to right. So, if D and E are expressions with
>   possible side-effects,

```
D :: E
```

> is translated to

```
{val x = D; E.::(x)}
```

> in order to maintain the left-to-right order of operand evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

In scala methods which ends with `:` got applied in reverse order.

So when you write `a::list` it is actually `list.::(a)`. String doesn't have :: method, so the solution is to write `List().::("a")` or `Nil.::("a")`

Answer (score 1):

Because of operator precedence. In Scala methods which ends with `:` are right associative. So you should call `List().::("a")`

If you want to use left associative method then you should write List("a") ++ List(), but that's not always a good choice, cause it has linear execution time